# Interesting properties of complex tori as groups and how they affect our understanding of elliptic curves

Tags: group-theory, elliptic-curves

I'm finishing up a small project I've written up for my final year of college, where I was given the objective to learn about elliptic curves and write a paper on what I've learned. I'm writing for an audience that knows basic commutative algebra and complex analysis (up until just before Riemann surfaces), and I am proving everything by first principles.

How I structured the paper so far is as follows:

1. Defined algebriac curves, (proved Hilbert's Nullstellensatz in the appendix)
2. Proved Bézout's theorem using resultants and derived some properties of cubics such as the Cayley-Bacharach theorem
3. Proved that every non-singular cubic curve in the plane is equivalent to a cubic in Weierstrass form by a change of variables and are therefore elliptic curves
4. Defined the group law on elliptic curves and proved it was associative
5. Defined  complex tori, elliptic functions and the Weierstrass-$\wp$ function. Showed that every complex torus is isomorphic to an elliptic curve and vice versa

Now I am exploiting this isomorphism to derive properties of the group law on the elliptic curve. So far I've proved that the group law on an elliptic curve is divisible, and that $E[n]\cong (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})\times (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}).$

My question is this: is there any other interesting facts about the group law that can be derived from this isomorphism? I want to make all of the work put in to read through everything seem more "worthwhile".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think that it is both too broad, and also not entirely appropriate in the first place.  It appears that you are asking the folk on MSE to do your research for you.  If this is for a class, then you need to do your own work.  If this is for something publishable, this is the kind of work which could merit a coauthorship.

Comment: @Xander Henderson On reflection I think you're right (although I don't agree with your reasoning - this is neither for a class, or for something publishable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show using this description the nice description of what the endomorphisms of the group are (either $\mathbb{Z}$ or an order in an imaginary quadratic field, depending on which lattice you chose).

Comment: And that they are the same as holomorphic maps $\Bbb{C/L\to C/L}$ fixing $0$, ie. any holomorphic map $E\to E$ is of the form $P\to [a]P+Q$ where $a = n$ or $n+\tau m$ depending if the latttice has CM or not